# Running a command if subfolder contains video files in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I would like a execute a command if a subfolder or subfolders of the startfolder contains the following video file types .mp4 .mov .wmv .avi

i.e. can multiple wildcards be used with if exist?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
color 0B

SET STARTFOLDER=C:\Users\%Username%\LocalData\Video Files

for /d %%d in ("%STARTFOLDER%\*") do (
for %%f in ("%%d") do (
If exist "%%f\*.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi" (
    Echo subfolder or subfolder of subfolder contains a video file
    Echo  ***This bit not working***
)
)
```

Comment: Would really need to know what you plan on doing if their are files in the sub folder.  This could change the code a bit if we don't know the whole picture.

Comment: You cannot state multiple file patterns at `if exist`; hence add an `if exist` line per each pattern and do a conditional `call`; and remove the inner `for %%f` loop which is completely useless: `if exist "%%~d\*.mp4" call :SUBROUTINE` for each file pattern...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want the subfolders checked, and not the sub-subfolders, here's one simple way to do it.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET STARTFOLDER=C:\Users\%Username%\LocalData\Video Files

for /d %%d in ("%STARTFOLDER%\*") do (
    pushd "%%~d"
    dir /b *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi 1>nul 2>nul
    if !errorlevel!==0 echo "%%~d"
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Color 0B
Set "StartFolder=%UserProfile%\LocalData\Video Files"
Set i=0
For /R "%StartFolder%" %%A In (*.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi) Do (
    2>Nul Set InFld[|Find "]=%%~dpA">Nul 2>&1||(Set/A i+=1
        Set "InFld[!i!]=%%~dpA"))
If %i% Equ 0 (Echo No video files within the tree: %StartFolder%
    GoTo :EndIt)
Echo= The following folders within %StartFolder% contain a video file:
For /L %%I In (1,1,%i%) Do Echo= !InFld[%%I]:%StartFolder%=!
:EndIt
Echo=
Pause
Exit/B
```

Comment: That's great nearly there but if the CCTV file(s) are found in a  subfolder 2 or 3 levels deep, how do I have the just the top level subfolder returned as a variable in the final loop?